# distribution plot with seaborn

Tags: plot, seaborn

i would like to plot the distribution of "Recency" variable (see the image) but i got value in the Y_axis from 0,0000 to 0,0016. I would like to change them by the frequency to be more clear and understable.
Any idea please

```
# Distribution of recency, frequency, monetary
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize = (10, 20))
for idx, val in enumerate(df_user.drop('COMPANY_CODE', axis = 1)):
      sns.distplot(df_user[val], ax = ax[idx], hist=True)
```

plt.tight_layout()

[image]

Comment: `histplot` has an option `stat=`which can be `“count”`, `“frequency”`, `“density”` or `“probability”` (Seaborn version 0.11.1)

Comment: Note that if you want to show the [kde curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation), you get a y-axis with [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `log_scale=True`

```
# Distribution of recency, frequency, monetary
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize = (10, 20))
for idx, val in enumerate(df_user.drop('COMPANY_CODE', axis = 1)):
      sns.histplot(df_user[val], ax = ax[idx], hist=True, log_scale=True)
```

Comment: thank but it does not work , i get this error : TypeError: distplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'log_scale'

Comment: try histplot instead of distplot